# How to add random offset to each date column of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add random offset to each date column of dataframe.

```
`df['date_offset'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, df.shape[0])

df['from_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
df['to_date'] = df['from_date'] + datetime.timedelta(days=df['date_offset'])`
```

But it's giving error as expected.

`TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series`

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['to_date'] = df['from_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['date_offset'], unit='d')
#df['to_date'] = datetime.datetime.now() + pd.to_timedelta(df['date_offset'], unit='d')
```

If need add random days without times use:

```
 a = np.random.randint(1, 100, df.shape[0])
 df['to_date'] = pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() + pd.to_timedelta(a, unit='d')
```

Or:

```
df['to_date'] = pd.to_datetime(a, unit='d', origin=datetime.datetime.now())
```